How can I update my React component after submiting the form data properly and without refreshing the page?
I'm fairly new to React and was trying some things out but got stuck with this issue. Basically I have (for now) on-memory objects that are sent to the FrontEnd from a server which is just an array of objects, and I get them like this:
function Projects() {

    const [prjs, setProjects] = useState("");


    useEffect(() => {const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("/api/home");
            setProjects(response.data);
            /* console.log(response); */
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Failed to make request: ", err)
        }
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);

    return <div>
        {Array.isArray(prjs) ? prjs.map(project => (

            <div key={project.id} className="note">
                <p>{project.ProjectName}</p>
                <span>{project.Status}</span>
                <p>{project.Created}</p>
            </div>
        )) : <p>Error in fetching data.</p>} 
    </div>

}

The next part is a simple form that just takes a single line of input from the user and I fill it with some extra things and is where I have an issue.
function Forms() {

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        ProjectName: '',
        Status: 'Pending',
        Created: date,
      });
    
      function handleChange(e) {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      };
    
    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await axios.post("/api/post", formData);
            console.log("Form data sent successfully: ", response.data);
        }
         catch (err) {
            console.error("There was an error in the request: ",err);
        }
    };
    
      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="ProjectName"
            placeholder="Enter your project name"
            value={formData.ProjectName}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      );
};

This is where the problem began, after submitting the data I tried to update the projects shown on screen in a couple of ways namely the dependency array and some other slightly more brute-force methods that also didn't work. What can I do here so that when the form is sent the projects I show the user update dynamically? If there are also ways to improve my code I am also eager to know, I am trying to learn as much as possible, thank you in advance and apologies if this is a bad question.

Move the logic for storing, changing and handling the projects state to a higher component. In the example below I've changed Projects to a "parent" component which is reponsible for the aforementioned logic.
function Projects() {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  const getProjects = async () {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("/api/home");
      setProjects(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to make request: ", err)
    }
  };

  const updateProjects = async (formData) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/post", formData);
      console.log("Form data sent successfully: ", response.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("There was an error in the request: ",err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProjects();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ProjectsView projects={projects} />
      <Forms updateProjects={updateProjects} setProjects={setProjects} />
    </>
  );
}

As you can see Projects passes the projects to the ProjectsView component, which has the responsibility of showing the projects.
function ProjectsView({ projects }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {projects.length > 0 ? projects.map(project => (
        <div key={project.id} className="note">
          <p>{project.ProjectName}</p>
          <span>{project.Status}</span>
          <p>{project.Created}</p>
        </div>
        )) : <p>Error in fetching data.</p>
      } 
    </div>
  );
}

Here below the Forms component will be able to update the projects state by using the setProjects dispatcher that is passed to the component. Next to updating the items on the server, update the state simultaneously.
It would be even better if the /api/post call returns the updated list and update projects with the response data. This way the projects state will always contain the information that is stored on the server.
function Forms({ updateProjects, setProjects }) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    ProjectName: '',
    Status: 'Pending',
    Created: date,
  });

  function handleChange(e) {
    setFormData({ 
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateProjects(formData);
    setProjects(prevData => [...prevData, formData]);
  }

  return ( 
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input 
        type="text"
        name="ProjectName"
        placeholder = "Enter your project name"
        value={formData.ProjectName}
        onChange={handleChange}
      /> 
      <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
    </form>
  );
};

